# Pointer will not return the address of a char type

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;

int b = 25;
char x = 'x'; 

int* p = &b;
int* p2 = &x;

int main()
{

  cout << "Pointer p is pointing to the address of variable b: " << p << endl;
  cout << "Pointer p2 is pointing to the address of variable x: " << p2 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This code will not give me the address of the variable x. It does not compile. It gives me an error as below:

**error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘int*’ in initialization**

If I run this code with only the integer type I get a hexadecimal address of the variable a.

I am confused because supposedly, int* p2 = &x; should create a integer pointer to the integer address of the single char 'x' as well.

So why can I get the address of a integer but not the address of a char type???

Comment: `int* p2 = &x;` - But there is no `int` at `x`. Casts don't magically convert one thing into another, they just tell the compiler to "please interpret the bits over there as if they were of this other type". It's on *you* to ensure that what you tell the compiler to do makes sense. If it does not, you get whatever garbage result you asked for (or sometimes you get lucky and the compiler stops you).

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of your code would be undefined: your friendly compiler is helping you.

`&x` is a `char*` type pointing to a `char` object, and attempting to convert that to an `int*` type is a violation of the *strict aliasing* rule.

One fix would be to write `char* p2 = &x;` and `(const void*)p2` in the corresponding `std::cout` statement to circumvent the calling of the special overload that `std::cout` has for `const char*` types.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This does work but now leaves me even more confused. It returned an address in 'int' form, so now I wonder exactly what a pointer is. I guess I will need to do some more research on pointers. Thanks again for the quick response/

Comment: @Clan a pointer is nothing but a variable that holds the address of (points to) some other thing (of some type). It's a sign saying "that's it, over there" - nothing more.